# map existing database to model that creates another database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, mapping

I am using CodeFirst approach, EF 4.0. I have model of tables that application uses. However I want to use another database as encyclopedia, meaning this database has a lot of data and these data is interconnected by foreign key. I have declared DbSet of my external datebase. However when model is generated, all entities that has to exist within my external DB, are placed as empty tables in my main DB. So here is the question. How can I specify for some entities to use external DB while for other use main DB?

Comment: why not using two seperate models?

Comment: because there is dependencies beetween them.

Comment: Then you will endup with two different databases with foreign key relations between them? I do not think you can have foreign key relations in different databases (cross database referential integrity is not supported in SQL server)...

Comment: No, foreign keys are beetween the tables in these two databases.

Comment: then it is better to seperate your models...